# How to reuse session for Poco::Net::HTTPSClientSession

Tags: c++11, https, openssl, poco-libraries

I have declared a static member variable of class Input_output_class()

Session::Ptr c_pSecureSession=nullptr;

For every request GET/PUT/DELETE/HEAD, I have to create an object of the class Input_output_class(). In the member function of the class
I am creating a session as follows 
Function Get()

```
{
if(c_pSecureSession)
{
    s_sess = HTTPSClientSession(host, port, pContext, c_pSecureSession); 
}
else
{
   s_sess = HTTPSClientSession(host, port, pContext);
}
 //pContext is a defaultClientContext from singleton Poco::Net::SSLManager 

s_sess->sendRequest(request);
c_pSecureSession = s_sess->sslSession();
cout <<" c_pSecureSession " << c_pSecureSession <<endl;

//Handle response below

 }
```

SSL MANAGER Singleton init code
——————

```
{
Poco::SharedPtr<Poco::Net::InvalidCertificateHandler> ptrHandler = new Poco::Net::AcceptCertificateHandler(false);
Poco::Net::Context::Ptr ptrContext = new Poco::Net::Context(Poco::Net::Context::CLIENT_USE, "");
ptrContext->enableSessionCache(true);
Poco::Net::SSLManager::instance().initializeClient(0, ptrHandler, ptrContext);

}
```

What I am seeing that session is not being reused and I am getting a new c_pSecureSession pointer for every request.

Could you please help me how to make use of session cacheing ..

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the basics - the `c_pSecureSession` is a `Poco::AutoPtr`, so will be a different instance every time. However, the underlying bare pointer will always be the same - that's the idea behind the smart pointer paradigm - many smart pointers wrap one "naked" pointer.

It is not clear from the code you posted how are you "reusing" a `nullptr` `Session` - in order to do that, you'd have to create a `Session` manually before (but how, when you have no socket yet?), or first create a `HTTPSClientSession` and then get it out from there for the subsequent ones (doable).

But, let's make it simple - you don't need the `c_pSecureSession` and you don't need to recreate session for every request - create it only once:

```
s_sess = HTTPSClientSession(host, port, pContext);
```

Since you already have the caching enabled for context, the underlying session in `s_sess` will be reused, just send/receive from it.

Note that, in order to cache sessions, caching must be enabled on the server side as well and sessions may also have expiration time - if the underlying session expires, a new one will be recreated automatically.

See [testCachedSession](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/poco-1.8.1/NetSSL_OpenSSL/testsuite/src/HTTPSClientSessionTest.cpp#L326) for an example on how to deal with sessions.

Comment: Thanks Alex for the response. I just edited the code as it was looking like I was trying to reuse nullptr.

Comment: Thanks again I missed to set keepalive on session ..that is why it was not working. Now it is working.